# Перевод языка Kotlin на Java

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

У меня есть активный фрагмент от нижней панели (т.е bottom menu) на языке котлина. Активи тоже на языке котлин, теперь я хотел в одной из активити сделать чат на языке java, а переписывать bottom menu на языке java для меня трудно, как можно преобразовать язык Kotlin на java и возможно ли это в одном из фргаментов? код который нужно преобразовать снизу

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false)
    }
```

Comment: Создайте Java класс, скопируйте туда этот метод, AndroidStudio должен автоматом перевести код.

Comment: не получается, пробывал :(

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) throws NullPointerException {
    if (inflater == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("inflater is null");
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
}
```

Comment: if с проверкой на null в таком виде явно лишний. Это AS так конвертирует?